# unable to delete image after opening it in vb.net app

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, dispose

I have this code:

```
Dim xx as image
xx = image.fromfile(Fileloc)
picturebox.image = xx
```

And i can't delete the file even though I've loaded it into a picture box. If I add this line:

```
xx.dispose
```

the picture box becomes a big red X.

I only want to delete the images when my application is closing (they are temp files). So shall I just dispose them before I delete them?

Comment: Yes, dispose them before you delete them.  That releases the lock on the file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't use `Image.FromFile`, it keeps the file open.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) :

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

Do that instead :

```
Dim xx as Image
Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(Fileloc)
    xx = Image.FromStream(str)
End Using
picturebox.Image = xx
```

The file is closed after the image is loaded, so you can delete the file if you need to

Comment: That doesn't help, it is still associated with the same file.

Comment: No, it's not... the Image is only associated with the stream, which is closed at the end of the Using block. It doesn't even know the filename... I've used this technique for some time and I'm certain it works fine.

Comment: It's done implicitly at the end of the Using block (actually it calls Dispose, which in turn calls Close)