# vb.net delete file used by another process

Tags: vb.net

I Have here a simple code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Button 1
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\1.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Button 2
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    IO.File.Delete("D:\1.jpg")
End Sub
```

When i press button 1 to import an image from file then i wanted to delete this image after press button 1 there is an error "The process cannot access the file 'D:\1.jpg' because it is being used by another process."

that error happen when i press button 2 , any solution ?

---

(Edited) : Solution Here [unable to delete image after opening it in vb.net app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079428/unable-to-delete-image-after-opening-it-in-vb-net-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Image.FromFile` method locks the file until the `Image` object is disposed.  Setting the `Image` property of a `PictureBox` to `Nothing` does not dispose the `Image` object.  You need to do that explicitly:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
IO.File.Delete("D:\1.jpg")
```

Comment: yeah that's work good but can you imagine i wrote this code 

PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\1.jpg")

PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\1.jpg")

(i write the same code many times)
when i make Dispose to the Image the error still ..
there is any solution ? thanks btw

Comment: If you assign the file path to the `ImageLocation` property of the `PictureBox` instead of calling `Image.FromFile` and setting the `Image` property then you won't lock the file at all, so that would solve your immediate problem. You really should be disposing your `Image` object either way though, so you might consider putting the code to dispose an existing `Image` and load a new one into its own method and then call that wherever you need it rather than repeating that code all over.